# WC in C with different child processes

Tags: c, linux

I open a question about a C program that simulates the `wc` command through 3 different child processes

Can someone help me identify the issue with this program. Here is the link to the question i asked this morning:

[Write a WC simulator in C with different Child Processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20446181/write-a-wc-simulator-in-c-with-different-child-processes)

Seems no one looked at my previous question, so I am trying to open a new one.

Comment: You should not post a new question just to point to your previous one. If you get no answers, try to improve the question. If you  are desperate, offer a bounty :-)

Comment: I improved it a lot, now i am just missing something on the functions that count the characters and the words, as for now only the lines are  correct in the count.

Comment: Also i would offer a bounty but i cant until the day after tomorrow.